# Solve command doesn't work (i'm beginner)

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I try to perform the equation

[image: 9.897527129=9.780327\left( 1+0.0053024\sin ^{ 2 }{ x } -0.0000058\sin { 2x } \right)]

by writing:

```
    Solve[9.897527129 == 
   9.780327 (1 + 0.0053024 (Sin[x])^2 - 0.0000058 Sin[2 x]) && -90 <= 
   x <= 90, x, Reals]
```

I'm actually press Shift+Enter and it happens nothing. Can you figure out what's wrong?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Solve commands works fine,give you `{}` it means No solution.

Comment: Use NSolve to compute this equation

Answer (score 4):

Inputting:

```
Solve[9.897527129 == 
   9.780327 (1 + 0.0053024 (Sin[x])^2 - 0.0000058 Sin[2 x]) && -90 <= 
   x <= 90, x, Reals]
```

Returns `{}`. This means "no solution", as Mariusz Iwaniuk commented. In these cases, it's usually helpful to plot both sides of the equation in question, especially since it is being solved over a real domain:

```
Plot[{9.897527129, 
  9.780327 (1 + 0.0053024 (Sin[x])^2 - 0.0000058 Sin[2 x])}, {x, -90, 
  90}]
```

> [image: Equations do not equal]

In this case, it's quite obvious that the two curves never intersect, so there is no solution.

If `Solve` fails but they do appear to intersect, then usually `Solve` will provide an error message relating a sort of failure (e.g. this system cannot be solved with the methods available to `Solve`, or similar) and you may wish to try `NSolve` or `FindRoot` instead. If there is no error message, then it may be that your functions simply behave strangely near the supposed intersection point (more likely than you might expect), or that `Solve` has legitimately missed a solution (which may be a bug).

Worst comes to worst, `NMinimize` and `FindMinimum` can be used to minimize the squared difference between the two sides of the equation for the variable in question, which will almost always return a solution of some variety. Whether or not that solution is useful is a case by case question that is left as an exercise to the reader.